# Div slides in with animation, but never slides back

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I am trying to make a div slide into the left of the screen using .animate().  It works initially, but then it doesn't slide back.  Only in.  Any suggestions as to why it's not working or better solutions would be awesome :)

EDIT: Right now the function below is being called onclick.

```
$(function() {
  toggleMobileMenu = function() {
    var menu = $('#mobile-side-menu');

    if( menu.css('left', -250) ) {
        menu.animate({left: 0}, 400, function(){
            positionValue = 0;
        });
    } else { 
        menu.animate({'left': '-250'},400);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You want it to slide over immediately or when it's being hovered over? When do you want it to slide back?

Comment: I want it to slide in when a button is clicked... Right now I'm using an onclick on a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is another way to do the animation if I correctly understand what you want.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZEH5b/

Mainly this bit...

```
$(function() {
    var block = $("#block");
    var slid = false;
    block.click(toggleMobileMenu);

    function toggleMobileMenu() {
        if (slid) {
            block.animate({left: "+=250"}, 400, function () { slid = false; });
        }
        else {
            block.animate({left: "-=250"}, 400, function() { slid = true; });
        }
    }
});
```

I think the animation, triggered by a button can be made to apply to a menu relatively easily.

Comment: I want to use this method but the "slid" variable doesn't update after animation.

Comment: Not sure I follow, is it not working correctly in the fiddle? For me the block moves left or right when clicked depending on what slid is.

Comment: Yeah, in fiddle it's working correctly.  I've added var slid = false to my function but after the entire function runs it still slid = false.

Comment: `$(function() {
  toggleMobileMenu = function() {
   var menu = $('#mobile-side-menu');
    var slid = false;

   if( slid ) {
      menu.animate({left: '-=250'},400, function() {
        slid = false;
        return slid;
      });
   } else { 
      menu.animate({left: '+=250'}, 400, function() {
        slid = true;
        return slid;
      });
   }
    console.log('slid = ' + slid);
  }
});`

Comment: Try declaring slid outside of your toggleMobileMenu function. Also, I don't think you need the `return slid` lines.

Comment: I rewrote the example a little bit to be a little close to what I think you should wind up having.

Comment: Ha!  Declaring slid outside of the function worked.  Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You are using `.css()` method as a setter which returns a jQuery object and an object is a truthy value in JavaScript, so your code doesn't reach to the `else` part. It should be:

```
if ( menu.css('left') === '-250px' ) {
   // ... 
}
```

Comment: Ahhh...  I see what you mean by using it as a "setter."  However, it doesn't seem to be a good comparator because it jumps to my "else" instead.

Comment: @JIGGABITS I assumed that you have set the `left` property to `-250px` in your CSS, you can check the retuned value by logging it, `console.log()`. As a sidenote, you can use jQuery `.stop()` method before calling `.animate()` for having better animations.

Answer (score 0):

**CSS**

```
#mobile-side-menu{position:relative;left:-250;display:block;}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mobile-side-menu">
    <li>Home</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Stuff</li>
</ul>
<button id="mobile-menu-move">Show Menu</button>
<button id="mobile-menu-back">Remove Menu</button>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function () {
    var $menu = $('#mobile-side-menu');
    var $slideButton = $('#mobile-menu-move');
    var $backButton = $('#mobile-menu-back');
    $slideButton.on('click', function () {
        $menu.animate({
            left: "0"
        }, 400, function () {});
    });
    $backButton.on('click', function () {
        $menu.animate({
            left: "-250"
        }, 400, function () {});
    });
});
```

[<kbd>jsFiddle</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/QFqz6/)

Answer (score 0):

isnt this easyer done with just css and a onclick event changing the id tag of the div:

```
#itemclicked{
transition:0.5s; /*also do transitions specific for webkit, moz etc...search google for css transitions*/

margin-left:-250px;
/*and the rest of the css*/
}
```

and the onclick

```
onclick="javascript:document.getElementById('item').value='itemclicked'"
```